# How to retrieve total number of tx for a single token in an address using Web3?

Tags: web3js

How can i retrieve the total number of transactions from an address for a specific token using web3 library?

For example i need to get the total number of tx to the dead address for the TokenA.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```js
const events = await erc20Contract.getPastEvents('Transfer', {
    filter: { to: 0xdead },
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
})
```

This gets you all transfer events for a certain ERC20 token.